# java.lang.ClassFormatError: org/eclipse/wb/internal/core/databinding/utils/CoreUtils when launching design view

Tags: java, eclipse

Anyone knows what kind of error is this?
I am not sure and i couldn't find anything wrong from my codes..
I can run my codes with no errors..

java.lang.ClassFormatError: org/eclipse/wb/internal/core/databinding/utils/CoreUtils 
this error shows up when i change it to design view..

Full context stack trace:

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: org/eclipse/wb/internal/core/databinding/utils/CoreUtils
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.swing.databinding.parser.DatabindingParser.<init>(DatabindingParser.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.swing.databinding.parser.DatabindingParser.parse(DatabindingParser.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.swing.databinding.SwingDatabindingFactory.createProvider(SwingDatabindingFactory.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.databinding.parser.DatabindingRootProcessor.process(DatabindingRootProcessor.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser.callRootProcessors(JavaInfoParser.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser.getRoot(JavaInfoParser.java:415)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser.parseRootMethods(JavaInfoParser.java:322)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser.parse(JavaInfoParser.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser.access$9(JavaInfoParser.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser$1.runObject(JavaInfoParser.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser$1.runObject(JavaInfoParser.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.utils.execution.ExecutionUtils.runDesignTime(ExecutionUtils.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser.parse(JavaInfoParser.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.internal_refreshGEF(DesignPage.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.access$9(DesignPage.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage$8$1.run(DesignPage.java:449)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4734)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage$8.run(DesignPage.java:446)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:466)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.ProgressMonitorDialog.run(ProgressMonitorDialog.java:527)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.internal_refreshGEF_withProgress(DesignPage.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.internal_refreshGEF(DesignPage.java:415)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.UndoManager.refreshDesignerEditor(UndoManager.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.refreshGEF(DesignPage.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.actions.RefreshAction.run(RefreshAction.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.actions.DesignPageAction.run(DesignPageAction.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.errors.JavaExceptionComposite.doRefresh(JavaExceptionComposite.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.errors.ExceptionComposite$3.widgetSelected(ExceptionComposite.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4172)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
```

Edited: 
Everything is fixed after i re-installed my eclipse.

Comment: can you also add, what comes for caused by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This usually occurs when the class is malformed or the jar which you are referring is corrupt, Can you try unzipping the jar and see where this class is and check if its accessible - what you are using

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean? Unzipping the jar where the class is? All other .java files (UI files) cannot be viewed in design view :O